# Maven how to automate installation of dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, war

I have 3 projects, A->B->C in that dependency order. Currently everytime I make a  change to B or C I have to go to the directory and do a `mvn clean install` in order to install it into the local repository. It is troublesome if I have to do this every time the projects updates.

How can I do it such that every time I do a `mvn clean package` on `A`, it will automatically build and install my dependent projects `B` and `C` into the local repository?

Comment: Make a multi module build from it...cause it looks like they belong together...

Answer (score 2):

Create a parent project for all your projects A,B,C and then add all your child project on the parent `pom.xml` file something like this

```
  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
  </modules>
```

Its called maven multi module project mentioned by **@khmarbaise**

Here are some example for this

1. [How do I create a multi-module project in Eclipse?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-multi-module-project-in-eclipse.html)
2. [Maven Multi module tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-multi-module-tutorial)
3. [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

By use of multi module project you will get plenty of benefits like

1. Anytime you can add any new project with all of the current project
2. Separation of project is good for code cleanup
3. You can build Single project or You can build all project in one go.
4. Duplicacy of jar can be easily ignore .
5. Maven take care of the build order for you.
6. One single Jenkins job to build everything.

Plenty of other benefits.But remember if there will some pros then cons also there,its totally now what you want to use .

Comment: Worth mentioning also that to rebuild you should do a `mvn install` on the parent project.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the solution I provided to the question [Maven 2 Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934027/maven-2-projects/30935138#30935138), since it is the pattern I usually use when building project with a certain complexity.

Summarizing you would have to create a main Maven project which has three submodules, say master, platform and parent.

The main project has simply the order in which the other projects will be evaluated by Maven

The master pom contains the list of project to be built and their order (aka Reactor order)

The platform pom contains all information about your platform, like JDK version, maven plugin versions, encoding and so on.

The parent pom has the platform pom as a parent and contains all global GAV information about the dependencies you are going to use in your project (Spring, CXF, junit, log4j etc.)