# Build all using maven pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

Say, I have 5 maven projects, some of which are dependent on another. now to build all project I need to build projects which are independent first, then the dependent ones. so basically I have use install command five times for different projects.

is there any way to create one pom to build all 5 projects with a single install command?

so far I created another project, the pom of which has dependencies of those five projects. It doesn't build those projects, rather it takes the jar from the built projects.

What do I need to do to build all using single pom?

Comment: Take a look at Maven [multiple modules build](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Comment: I gave a possible approach to this kind of problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934027/maven-2-projects/30935138#30935138)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Tunaki, that was so simple, I used the following pom in another project, which builds other projects together.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ngp.ipas</groupId>
    <artifactId>build.all</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <module>../../framework/ipas.proj1</module>
    <module>../../framework/ipas.proj2</module>
    <module>../../framework/ipas.proj3</module>
    <module>../../framework/ipas.proj4</module>
    <module>../../framework/ipas.proj5</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```