# How to add dependency of other local maven project to l local maven project in java (runtime and compile time)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two maven projects. Project A is dependent on project B. The dependencies are defined in the pom.xml (as shown here : [how to add dependency of other maven project to my current maven project in java eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208765/how-to-add-dependency-of-other-maven-project-to-my-current-maven-project-in-java))  and the compiler is happy. However when Project A startups it throws a ClassNotFoundException. I am using eclipse.

How do I fix this runtime exception?

Comment: Is project B a *Maven dependency* or just an Eclipse dependency? Is project B on the build path of project A?
Also, the class which is not found, where is it located within project B? Is it in its `src/main/java` folder or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Build path was the problem : properties -> java build path -> add project. Lovely

Answer (score 0):

Adding Project B artifact as dependency to Project A should do it , as answered in the question link you posted. Have you set scope for the dependency?
(Sorry, this should have been a comment but dont have enough reputation for that!)

Comment: The scope I have not defined. Runtime class loading might be a bit tricky because it is a spring application.